# Ableton crash when i open ezbass

Tags: daw, ableton-live

i recently add ableton 11 to my pc. Everything is fine. I want to use ezbass from toontrack. When i first open ezbass, everything is fine but when i save my project and load my project next time, when i want to open ezbass again, my ableton crash. I also went to ableton and toontrack websites buf couldnt find anything usefull. Can anybody here be kind and help me please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while related to music equipment, it's more about software technical support and not music practice/theory.

Comment: Maybe slightly more related (but I'm not really sure): https://sound.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com/